# nvidia-smi : Kernel API version mismatch

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda

I am installing cuda-10.0 on my ubuntu 18.04 system. I have followed the instructions as per the official website : https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/

While running the samples provided with cuda toolkit to verify the installation, I get following error:

> /usr/local/cuda-10.0/samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery Starting...
>
> CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
>
> cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
>   -> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
>   Result = FAIL

I ran the command "nvidia-smi" and got below output:

> Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error

Below is the output of command "dmesg"

> [4424407.320909] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 440.82, but
>                    NVRM: this kernel module has the version 440.44.  Please
>                    NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
>                    NVRM: components have the same version.
>
> [4426448.420756] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 340.108, but
>                    NVRM: this kernel module has the version 440.44.  Please
>                    NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
>                    NVRM: components have the same version.

Output of command "cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version"

> NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  440.44  Sun Dec  8 03:38:56 UTC 2019
>
> GCC version:  gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)

I am installing this on a remote system which I am accessing through ssh and AnyDesk (to access through GUI). Is there any solution which would not require me to reboot my remote system. Given the current Corona situation, it might become problematic for me if I reboot the remote system.

Comment: My Ubuntu 20.04 Nvidia driver is 440.64, so don't know where you got the .82 version -- you should copy the samples  directory to a writeable location, and make the samples yourself, which will use your installed driver, and test your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH modificatioins.

Comment: @ubfan1  I think my Nvidia driver version is 440.44. Thats what it shows in the output of 'dmesg' command.
"  API mismatch: the client has the version 440.82, but NVRM: this kernel module has the version 440.44. "  

I think the kernel module refers to the Nvidia driver. I am not sure what is the client it is referring to.

Comment: Guessing the .run installer supplied the 440.82 Nvidia drivers where they got picked up when you build the samples.  I'd seen the supplied drivers being several versions older than the standard Ubuntu ones (in the deb installers), but not a newer one. Same solution applies, get rid of the non-system drivers. Easy way is to select a CUDA  installer without Nvidia drivers. Find where the .run installer put it's Nvidia code cuda/lib64 (?) and delete them, then the system version should be picked up . deb installer cleanup is messier, since all CUDA files depend upon the old versions.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when installing Nvidia drivers from a .run file downloaded from the Nvidia website.

Ubuntu has a `libnvidia-compute-4xx` package which provides some library version (440.82 in your case). The `nvidia-smi` provided by the .run file expects a slightly different version (440.44). The solution is to remove `libnvidia-compute-4xx`: `# apt purge libnvidia-compute-4xx`.

All Nvidia driver install guides tell you to remove apt packages using `# apt remove nvidia*`, but the `libnvidia-compute-4xx` package escapes that wildcard, causing this library version mismatch problem.

I found this solution by looking at the commands in this blog: https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_43825748/article/details/112979312.